# Missing parameters on submit / button outside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a form and a button outside the form. I want to submit the form using the button, so i have written some jquery code. Everything seems to work fine, except one thing. After submit action button's name and value aren't being send (in this case: page=2). How can I fix it? Thanks in advance for help.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#test-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
    <input type="text" name="example">
  </form>
  <button name="page" value="2">2</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I think it is working fine just check in console while running the snippet

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP no it doesn't submit the value of the `<button>` tag  - read the question

Comment: Then why dont you move button inside form

Comment: If you move button inside form you can also remove the javascript written to trigger form

Comment: In my application search criteria are at the top of a page and pagination is at the bottom, so form tags must have full length of page. Is it elegant?

Comment: @Wojtek see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815911/5947043) for an alternative approach you can use in that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button's value isn't submitted because it isn't considered part of the form (due to being outside the `<form>...</form>` tags).

As an alternative to [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815778/5947043) which is one correct way to do it, if for some reason you don't wish to move the button inside the form, then in HTML5 another option you have is to associate the button with the form via an attribute. This allows the button to be considered as part of the form despite being outside the tags.

As an added bonus, once the button is part of the form, you don't need any JavaScript to make it work - it will automatically be considered as a "submit" button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
    <input type="text" name="example" />
  </form>
  <button name="page" value="2" form="test-form">2</button>
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

See the "form" attribute discussed in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: intrigued as to why this would be downvoted. Does someone think it doesn't work in the circumstances described? Have they tested it?

Comment: Nice solution +1, I have a question about this. A few years ago I had to submit multiple forms with one button. Would it be possible with the form attribute to link multiple forms to this button? Or would I still have to solve this with for example I gave all the forms the same class and did it in JQuery with an onclick trigger.

Comment: @mrdeadsven good question. The documentation link I gave says " The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a `<form>` element in the same document". I'd take this to mean it can only contain 1 ID. After all...if it contained multiple form IDs, and you clicked it, how would the browser know which form you actually wanted to submit?

Comment: yea that sounds pretty logical now that I think about it :p, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The reason the button's data won't be submitted in the form is because the button is outside the form element. To fix this, place the button before the closing `</form>` tag so your code looks like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
        <input type="text" name="example">
                    <button name="page" value="2">2</button>
    </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Of course if you really wanted to add the button'a value to the handling page without the button being inside the form, you could just add this to the URL:

Instead of having

```
https://example.com/handler.php
```

As your action URL, add the button's values here:

```
https://example.com/handler.php?page=2
```

And put that in your form's action attribute like so:

```
<form id="testForm" method="get" action="https://example.com/handler.php?page=2">...</form>
```

And then the data will be submitted.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that once the button is inside the form, the JavaScript is no longer required.

Comment: Yes that is true @ADyson

Answer (score 0):

The form only submits the named values within the form.

You could use a hidden and assign the button value in the click event.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#button_value').val($(this).val());
  $('#test-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
                    <input type="text" name="example" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="page-no" id="button_value" />
  </form>
  <button name="page" value="2">2</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
<html>
```

Comment: simpler just to move the button inside the form, surely?

Comment: Correct that is an option.  I assumed if the button is outside the form there is a good reason.

Comment: There's a simpler way around that - see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815911/5947043

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden input element with name and value that you want to send inside the form.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#test-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
   <input type="text" name="example">
 <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2">
         
  </form>
  <button>Submit</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
<html>
```

Or else if you can place the submit button inside the form, you can remove the code for stimulating the submit action.
https://jsfiddle.net/yh4yvoe3/8/

Answer (score 0):

Of course your button value you won't be sent. As specified, it's outside the form.

Therefore when you submit the content, it isn't included.

Put it inside the form if you want it to be included, and then you don't need any jQuery or JavaScript.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <button type="submit" name="page" value="2">2</button>
  </form>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve by the following logic, add button name and value in the hidden field and append inside the form.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#test-form').append($("<input/>", {
        name: this.name, 
        value: this.value, 
        type: 'hidden'
   })).submit();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="get" action="#" id="test-form">
   <input type="text" name="example">
  </form>
  <button name="page" value="2">2</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can copy button using `.clone()` and insert copy of button into form using `.append()` and then submit the form

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var button = $(this).clone().hide();
  $('#test-form').append(button).submit();
});
```

Comment: button is out of form so `$('#test-form button').click();` doesn't trigger any event

Comment: I didn't see any button inside form please recheck

Comment: It's unclear how this would resolve anything. There's no button inside the form. And if the button _was_ inside the form, no script would be required

Comment: that's a weird and completely unnecessary workaround. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815911/5947043) for a saner solution (aside from just moving the button inside the form, which has already been suggested).

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP Problem fixed,